# how would I search the `/aems/dic/list` from a list of anchors?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, selenium-webdriver

I have the below code which is a part of an html:

```
<td><a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube</a></td>
<td><a data-category="news" href=http://kathack.com/party/aems/dic/list">Reddit</a></td>
<td><a href="http://kathack.com/party/aems">Kathack</a></td>
<td><a data-category="news" href="http://www.nytimes.com">New York Times</a></td>
```

now how would I search the `/aems/dic/list` and get the full url stored?

Comment: for similar tasks I use `nokogiri` gem

Comment: Can I have a bit of code to see how it can be done?

Comment: Can it be done using selenium-webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with `nokogiri`, something like this:

```
fragment = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse text
fragment.css("a").each do |link|
  href = link['href']
  return href if href =~ /\/aems\/dic\/list/
end
```

Comment: Suppose i do have a website `www.example.com` which has a webpage, and the description mentioned content is a part of the page,then how should i write it? a bit idea please share. as i never used `nokogiri`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a Mechanize::Page object `page`:

```
page.at('a[href*="/aems/dic/list"]')[:href]
#=> "http://kathack.com/party/aems/dic/list"
```

**Update**

For a longer example:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get 'http://www.example.com/'
page.at('a[href*="/aems/dic/list"]')[:href]
#=> "http://kathack.com/party/aems/dic/list"
```

Comment: Nice one ... `+1` to you :) Can you give me a full code - means Suppose the description mentioned `html` is a part of webpage `www.example.com` then how to start? Just to see as i used till now only `selenium`. and good documentation where i can be able to see more example with `Mechanize` - to see how to use the procedures of it.

Comment: Any Good suggestion would you like to me give regarding - How to use the docs? I am talking about this as, I am first time seeing such kind of docs. Basically I am from Oracle domain. The basic trouble I am suffering with the doc is that,not all the procedures has a tiny code to explain the syntax. So how to do such homework, to understand what procedure can be used how inside a code. The doc has such tiny codes with small amount of procedures, not for all. Any suggestions on that. I am really eager to know this platform,but the documentation sometime helps,sometime not.

Comment: As far as the docs, all I can say is maybe you'll get used to it. usually inspecting an objects methods is enough to know how to use it.

Comment: Could you please say- from where you got the `'a[href*="/aems/dic/list"]')[:href]`? I want to know this concept,so that I can use ti for other requirements also,if any I have!